# Bounded partial derivatives don't imply differentiability

Tags: multivariable-calculus

It's well known bounded partial derivatives imply continuity but I don't believe they imply differentiability. Is there a counterexample for this?

Answer (score 0):

The function $f\colon \mathbb{R}^2\to\mathbb{R}$ defined as
\begin{equation}
f(\boldsymbol{\mathrm{x}})=xe^{-\|\boldsymbol{\mathrm{x}}\|}, \quad \boldsymbol{\mathrm{x}}=(x,y)\in\mathbb{R}^2
\end{equation}
has partial derivatives
\begin{align}
\partial_x f(\boldsymbol{\mathrm{x}})&=\begin{cases}
\displaystyle e^{-\|\boldsymbol{\mathrm{x}}\|}-\dfrac{x^2}{\|\boldsymbol{\mathrm{x}}\|e^{\|\boldsymbol{\mathrm{x}}\|}},\quad &\boldsymbol{\mathrm{x}}\neq \boldsymbol{0},\\
1,&\boldsymbol{\mathrm{x}}= \boldsymbol{0}
\end{cases}\\
\partial_y f(\boldsymbol{\mathrm{x}})&=\begin{cases}
\displaystyle -\frac{xy}{\|\boldsymbol{\mathrm{x}}\|e^{\|\boldsymbol{\mathrm{x}}\|}},\quad &\boldsymbol{\mathrm{x}}\neq \boldsymbol{0},\\
0,&\boldsymbol{\mathrm{x}}= \boldsymbol{0}
\end{cases}
\end{align}
which are bounded in $\mathbb{R}^2$. But $f$ itself is not differentiable at $\boldsymbol{0}=(0,0)$.

---

A stronger result is that bounded partial derivatives imply Lipschitz continuity, and any Lipschitz continuous function is differentiable except for a set of Lebesgue measure zero. The function $f$ we defined above is Lipschitz continuous.